# using prestashop DB API in a php-cli project for testing?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have prestashop 1.7.2.0 installed on php 7.1.7 on nginx server.

I'm writing a module for prestashop and it will be way faster for me if I could use prestashop API for PHP-CLI in order to test the installation and the operation of my module.

specifically now I need to get `Db::getIntance()` to work.

so far I created the following script:

```
<?php
const PRESTASHOP_DIR = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'prestashop';

spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
    if (0 === strpos($className, 'InstallControllerConsole')) {
        $fileName = strtolower(str_replace('InstallControllerConsole', '', $className));
        require_once PRESTASHOP_DIR.'/controllers/console/' . $fileName . '.php';
    }
    if (0 === strpos($className, 'InstallControllerHttp')) {
        $fileName = strtolower(str_replace('InstallControllerHttp', '', $className));
        require_once PRESTASHOP_DIR.'/controllers/http/' . $fileName . '.php';
    }
    if (file_exists(PRESTASHOP_DIR.'/classes/' . $className . '.php')) {
        require_once PRESTASHOP_DIR.'/classes/' . $className . '.php';
    }
    if (0 === strpos($className,'Db') && file_exists(PRESTASHOP_DIR.'/classes/db/'.$className.'.php')) {
        require_once PRESTASHOP_DIR.'/classes/db/'.$className.'.php';
    }
});

require_once(PRESTASHOP_DIR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'classes'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'db'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'DbPDO.php');
require_once(PRESTASHOP_DIR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.inc.php');
require_once(PRESTASHOP_DIR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'vendor'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'autoload.php');

$a = Db::getInstance();
```

and I get the following Error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Db' not found in /Volumes/osx-storage/projects/luckylee/prestashop/prestashop/classes/db/DbPDO.php on line 32
```

when I tried to grep prestashop project for `Db` class I could only see an abstract class which means that something else extends and init it.

any idea how to resolve this ?

## update

it seems that I pointed to a pestashop directory that was just unzipped and not installed. when I pointed it to a directory that prestashop is properly configured, requiring only `config.inc.php` is enough.. but

when I do an insert to a table that I created, nothing happens and it doesn't return an error. any ideas?

I run the command:

```
    Db::getInstance()->insert(_DB_PREFIX_.'tuxinmod_cartype',['id_tuxmod_cartype'=>0],true);
```

and no changes in the database. why? :)

I created the table ps_tuxinmod_cartype.. and still i should have gotten an error and I don't. what am I missing ?

## update

ok omitting the `_DB_PREFIX_` from the insert statements do work! :) yay!!
but I really need to know when there is an error.

these are my error related configuration php.ini

```
display_errors => STDOUT => STDOUT
display_startup_errors => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => no value => no value
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 32767 => 32767
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
track_errors => On => On
xdebug.force_display_errors => On => On
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 32767 => 32767
xdebug.show_error_trace => On => On
```

i see no errors what so ever when I provide a table that doesn't exist

any ideas?

Comment: Have you included the config file (include('path to config/config.inc.php')) to "load" prestashop?

Comment: @sadlyblue yeap

Comment: sorry, didn't noticed it. you are loading the dbpdo class yourself. usually we don't need to do that. just the config.inc.php, same with the autoload from vendor. and when you are trying to load before the config, so the dbpdo extends a db class that it doesn't know yet. on a side not, do you have a prestashop folder inside prestashop?

Comment: @sadlyblue - prestashop directory does contain the prestashop files. if I only include the config.inc.php file the program terminates on the include cause it probably missing some variables definitions and because of that it stops the execution of my application.

Comment: @sadlyblue - thanks for the support so far. updated main post

Comment: if you use the `Db::getInstance()->insert()` you shouldn't specify the `_DB_PREFIX_`.

Comment: @sadlyblue - I just want to understand that I understand it properly.. i thought that DB_PREFIX is just the 'ps_'. am i right? so instead of 'ps_tuxinmod_cartype' to specify  'tux-inmod_cartype'?  and even then.. why I don't see any error ?why no exception was thrown ?

Comment: Yes, it usually corresponds to the ps_, and other usages of the same function don't include that. As for the no error, the php-cli could have a different settings. Have you turned on the _PS_MODE_DEV_ in prestashop `config/defines.inc.php` or in back office performance? If not, the errors could be ignore. Also check the php-cli settings with something like `php -i | grep error`

Comment: @sadlyblue - ahhmm.. i have dev enabled but the cli might be using a different php.ini then on the nginx server and that's why I can't see the errors. when I get home i'll check all of that. thanks a lot

Comment: @sadlyblue - thanks a lot. we are very close to resolving this issue. what's left is why I don't see error messages when I provide the wrong table name. provided output of "php -i".

Comment: @sadlyblue - ahh I have two computers and only on one of them I set the DEV to true :) oops! everything works now. please post it as an answer so i'll accept it. thanks for everything

Comment: Glad it's solved. I was running out of ideas of what it could be. I've answered with a short resume of these comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the Prestashop function in cli (or other scripts) we just need to include/require_once the `config/config.inc.php`.

Also, different from the `Db::getInstance()->execute()`, with `Db::getInstance()->insert()` you shouldn't specify the _DB_PREFIX_. The insert function will take care of that.

And to get the error output, we need to check if the dev mode is enabled in the `config/defines.inc.php` and that the php settings allow for the error display (with `php -i | grep error` or `phpinfo();` if using a web accessable script)

Comment: one more thing that I missed... of course to point the project to a prestashop directory that was properly installed and configured so it will be able to fetch the db configuration! :)